# Find HTML element with jQuery using effective style (style inherited from CSS class, not explicit on element)

Tags: jquery, html, css, xpath

I have a CSS class that has style `text-decoration-line`, and a HTML element that uses this class.

I want to be able to use a jQuery selector to get the element by the `text-decoration-line` style, not by the CSS class on the element. Something like:

```
$("span[style*='text-decoration-line']")
```

If I try to do that, jQuery doesn't recognize the style inherited by the class. If I explicitly set the style on the element, it works.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akvcwe6t/1/

I could use jQuery or XPath, either of them is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to loop through every element and check its computed style.

```
$("span").each(function(){
  if($(this).css('text-decoration-line')!='') {
    // do something

  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! The keyword to look for is `computed style`. I was seaching for `effective style` but that didn't lead me to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, to do this without jQuery, you can use `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("selector")).textDecoration`