# using css class style attribute in xpath (not inline style)?

Tags: selenium, xpath

How to define the style attribute from a css class in xpath?

Let consider the left side bar in SO. How can I write the xpath to search for element which have the `width:164px' defined in`left-side` class.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1esr.png)

Comment: If it's not shown as an attribute, you can't use it in xpath.  Why would you need to?

Comment: You could read an array of webelements, then cycle through them checking their width properties that way, but not via xpath that I know of.

Comment: I have a scenario where I have to use the attribute from the class as mentioned in another post something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486373/find-html-element-with-jquery-using-effective-style-style-inherited-from-css-cl

Comment: Are you using java or some other language?

Comment: Python, however the xpath is nothing to do with language binding.

Comment: It might with the selenium implementation - you'd need to use selenium to get the web element size.  I can show you an example of how I would do it in java, I don't code in python.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to get it with the element and then get css style from the element in code and perform the operation. However, I want to handle it only in pure xpath.

Comment: If it's not in the HTML document as XML, you won't be able to retrieve it using xpath, but good luck.